# samesite cookie attribute feature is not enabled in php 7.3.8 version

Tags: php, setcookie

**samesite cookie** attribute is not enabling on php version **7.3.8**?  Attribute is enabled on php 7.3.10 version and 7.2.11. 
    PHP 7.3.10 enabled attrbiute usng below code-

```php
setcookie('test', 'new', ['expires' => 0,'path' => '/','samesite' => 'None','secure' => false,'httponly' => true]);
```

Same code is using on php 7.3.8 but not able to enable the samesite attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Then write it old school.

Example:

```php
setcookie($name, $value, $expires, '/; SameSite=none;', $domain, false, true);
```